# get all lines between 2 strings when match is found

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I've got an XML-file that looks like this:

```
    <verzekerde>
          <voorletters>FD</voorletters>
          <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
          <achternaam>King</achternaam>
          <adres>
            <straat>Kingsroad</straat>
            <huisnummer>115</huisnummer>
            <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
            <postcode>1123 GP</postcode>
            <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
            <land>NL</land>
          </adres>
        </verzekerde>

<verzekerde>
      <voorletters>F</voorletters>
      <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
      <achternaam>Prince</achternaam>
      <adres>
        <straat>Prince Avenue</straat>
        <huisnummer>5</huisnummer>
        <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
        <postcode>1225 PG</postcode>
        <plaats>PRINCETOWN</plaats>
        <land>NL</land>
      </adres>
    </verzekerde>
    <verzekerde>
          <voorletters>C</voorletters>
          <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
          <achternaam>Queen</achternaam>
          <adres>
            <straat>Queensroad</straat>
            <huisnummer>11</huisnummer>
            <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
            <postcode>1113 GP</postcode>
            <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
            <land>NL</land>
          </adres>
        </verzekerde>
```

I want to extract all parts between `<verzekerde>` and `</verzekerde>` if the string KINGSTOWN is present, so the result should be:

```
<verzekerde>
              <voorletters>FD</voorletters>
              <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
              <achternaam>King</achternaam>
              <adres>
                <straat>Kingsroad</straat>
                <huisnummer>115</huisnummer>
                <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
                <postcode>1123 GP</postcode>
                <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
                <land>NL</land>
              </adres>
            </verzekerde>
        <verzekerde>
              <voorletters>C</voorletters>
              <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
              <achternaam>Queen</achternaam>
              <adres>
                <straat>Queensroad</straat>
                <huisnummer>11</huisnummer>
                <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
                <postcode>1113 GP</postcode>
                <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
                <land>NL</land>
              </adres>
            </verzekerde>
```

I have tried `sed -n '/KINGSTOWN/,/\<\/verzekerde\>/p'` but that only gave me the lines from `<plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>` until `</verzekerde>`

Is there a way to also get the lines up to `<verzekerde>`?
I want to integrate this in a bash-script.
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Don't manipulate XML as a text file. Use python, ruby, perl, php...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I edit it as a text file is that I'm familiar with grep, sed, and a little bit of awk. After manipulation I don't use the file as a xml-file. The only thing I'm looking for is a way to extract the tags between <verzekerde> and </verzekerde>

Comment: Well, apparently you don't know how to do it in those languages either...

Comment: So true. I'm not an expert, that's why I ask for help...

Answer (score 2):

Use `xpath` to grep in XML documents.

Given the following XML document.

```
<root>
<verzekerde>
      <voorletters>FD</voorletters>
      <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
      <achternaam>King</achternaam>
      <adres>
        <straat>Kingsroad</straat>
        <huisnummer>115</huisnummer>
        <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
        <postcode>1123 GP</postcode>
        <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
        <land>NL</land>
      </adres>
    </verzekerde>

<verzekerde>
  <voorletters>F</voorletters>
  <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
  <achternaam>Prince</achternaam>
  <adres>
    <straat>Prince Avenue</straat>
    <huisnummer>5</huisnummer>
    <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
    <postcode>1225 PG</postcode>
    <plaats>PRINCETOWN</plaats>
    <land>NL</land>
  </adres>
</verzekerde>
<verzekerde>
      <voorletters>C</voorletters>
      <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
      <achternaam>Queen</achternaam>
      <adres>
        <straat>Queensroad</straat>
        <huisnummer>11</huisnummer>
        <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
        <postcode>1113 GP</postcode>
        <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
        <land>NL</land>
      </adres>
    </verzekerde>
</root>
```

the following command

```
$ xpath -q -e '//verzekerde[adres/plaats/text()="KINGSTOWN"]' data.xml
```

extracts the nodes you are looking for

```
<verzekerde>
      <voorletters>FD</voorletters>
      <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
      <achternaam>King</achternaam>
      <adres>
        <straat>Kingsroad</straat>
        <huisnummer>115</huisnummer>
        <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
        <postcode>1123 GP</postcode>
        <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
        <land>NL</land>
      </adres>
    </verzekerde>
<verzekerde>
      <voorletters>C</voorletters>
      <tussenvoegsel> </tussenvoegsel>
      <achternaam>Queen</achternaam>
      <adres>
        <straat>Queensroad</straat>
        <huisnummer>11</huisnummer>
        <toevoeging> </toevoeging>
        <postcode>1113 GP</postcode>
        <plaats>KINGSTOWN</plaats>
        <land>NL</land>
      </adres>
    </verzekerde>
```

The command is on Debian in the following package:

```
$ dpkg -S $(type -p xpath)
libxml-xpath-perl: /usr/bin/xpath
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="</verzekerde>\n"} /KINGSTOWN/' xml
```

Comment: You should mention it's gawk-specific due to the multi-char `RS`. It would also add a `</verzekerde>\n` and an undesirable block at the end of the output if "KINGSTOWN" appeared after the last `</verzekerde>\n` in the input file. You need to test for `RT`.